# Study Circle for Solving Exercises from a Book

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, self-learning, problem-solving

I have always fantasized solving ALL the exercise problems from a book. But that never seems to happen. Its just easier to feel knowledgable by reading the theory, and also saves time. I know thats terrible practice (and I can feel my knowledge being shallow), but solving exercises is arduous. Its easy to stagnate on problems or fizzle out after much initial fanfare. The lack of solution manuals is also an issue- we just cannot check how satisfactory our solution is.

So I was thinking if this could be done in a group- with other interested parties. Like a specific study circle for solving problems- but from specific topics or books. We could pool resources, compare solutions and discuss techniques. Most importantly, there would be some motivation to keep going.

MathSE is great, but one cannot keep posting regarding different problems from one exercise set. Some might even be too simple to waste others time on, considering the scope and audience of MathSE. I am talking about a kind of sub-MathSE for specific books and exercises.

My proposition does not seem novel, I'm sure such forums exist- maybe locally in different universities. I just don't know where/how to find them. Maybe we could have different rooms for different topics/textbooks, or vote and choose monthly themes and targets?

Comment: What's your question within the scope of Math.SE?

Comment: This is the question you could be asking around your university, or possibly other places of learning near you. I just don't see how this site could be of any help in this case

Comment: This is not a mathematical question. You may want to try meta.

Comment: The question is not for meta either. Maybe math education?

Comment: Personal advice: whether you study in a group or on your own, you still need to solve a lot of exercises alone. This is the crucial part of learning. There's a lot of examples of solved problems including this site. Study group helps, but you need to continue on your own